# PHP including files

Tags: php

What's the difference between

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

and

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

I wonder what's the difference because when I 'echo' them, they're returning same path. Which do you prefer should I use and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are different

**_*FILE*_**

> The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned. Since PHP 4.0.2, **FILE** always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances.

source : [PHP magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Let's said, your document is `/var/www`,
and your index page is `/var/www/index.php`

```
dirname(__FILE__) == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

But if you drill-down to sub-folder like `/var/www/posts/index.php`

```
dirname(__FILE__) != $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
/var/www/posts    != /var/www
```

The use of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`__FILE__` always points to the current file path, and `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` points to the document root path ;-)

I prefer first one, as it is more semantic.

If you will try to compare the values of the files, that are located not in your docroot - then you'll get different values.

Answer (score 0):

The former one is a root folder for the HTTP server (or VirtualHost) and it is a server setting.

The latter is the folder containing the current file.

The usage is entirely based on requirements in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` when you want to reference your website's root folder from any where within your website or web application.

You will find using `dirname(__FILE__)` handy if you were including a file, that then needed to include some more files from the same directory. I use this in my [PHP wrapper for the Dribbble API](https://github.com/martinbean/dribbble-php)

```
class Dribbble {

    function __construct() {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/base.php');
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/shot.php');
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/player.php');
    }
}
```

This means I can just include `dribbble.php` from any where in my website or web application and not worry about also including `base.php`, `shot.php`, and `player.php` at the same time.